# ReactDOM not rendering element

Tags: reactjs

I fail to understand why the following would not render a button on the page:

```jsx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic Example</title>    
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="./build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="./build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="./build/react-with-addons.js"></script>



<script type="text/jsx">
      /** @jsx React.DOM */

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <button>Go</button>
      )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('container'));

 </script>  


  </body>
</html>
```

The only output i see in the console is:

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://fb.me/react-devtools
```

As I understand this is not an error message.

Comment: You are trying to render the same component you declaring. Also try to dont name your components as html existing ones.

Comment: does not help solve my issue

Comment: Hi, I am new to react and am getting the same error while running a simple 'Hello world' example. Is your query resolved ? Please update this page with answer that worked for you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

These are the minimal changes I found to make it work. (See also the [Getting Started](http://Facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) page.)

- Replace `./build/react-with-addons.js` with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js`.
- Replace `text/jsx` with `text/babel`.
- Delete the line `/** @jsx React.DOM */`.

But this can cause other error messages, at least in Firefox, in the console, although this doesn't affect the functionality of the example.